# Is my .asLongAs condition wrong?

Tags: java, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

Expected output should be 3 calls of
like,

1. https://someurl.net;limit=5;offset=0  (1st call will start from 0 offset everytime - Must)
2. https://someurl.net;limit=5;offset=5 (2nd call, limit + offsetvalue 0 + 5 = 5)
3. https://someurl.net;limit=5;offset=10 (3rd call, limit + offsetvalue 5 + 5 = 10)

Here is the code,

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class metadataAn extends Simulation {
    val getAssetURL = System.getProperty("getAssetURL", "https://someurl")
    val username = System.getProperty("username", "user")
    val password = System.getProperty("password", "user")

    val limit = Integer.getInteger("limit", 5).toInt
    val counter = 0

    val httpProtocol = http
        .basicAuth(username, password)
        .baseURL(getAssetURL)

    // Step-1 get total count
    val scn = scenario("Get Total assets")
            .exec(http("Number of Assets")
            .get(s"""/api/xyz;limit=1;offset=0""")
            .check(jsonPath("$.totalCount").findAll.saveAs("total"))
            )

    //.asLongAs(session => counter.getAndIncrement().equals("${total}/$limit")) // Throws error mentioned below
    .asLongAs(session => session.get("${counter}").equals("10"))
    {
        exec(http("List of Assets")
            .get(session =>s"""/api/xyz;limit=$limit;offset=${counter}""")
            .check(jsonPath("$.assets[*].id").findAll.saveAs("IdList"))
            )

        .foreach("${IdList}", "idlist") {
            exec(http("Add data")
                .post("""/api/xyz/${idlist}/data""")
                .body(StringBody(session =>s"""{some data....}"""))
                )
            }
        .exec(session => {
                val cnt = session("counter").as[String].toInt
                val increaseCounter = cnt + limit
                session.set("counter", increaseCounter)
                println("********COUNTER************: ====>>> " + increaseCounter)
                session})

    }
    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

It compiles but not able to enter into the loop.

```
---- Get Total assets ----------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done:1
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=1      KO=0     )
> Number of Assets                                         (OK=1      KO=0     )
================================================================================
```

==============================

**If I compile this with below condition**

```
.asLongAs(session => counter.getAndIncrement().equals("${total}/$limit"))
```

Throws Errors:

```
17:34:10.300 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - scala:34: value getAndIncrement is not a member of Int
17:34:10.301 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ -      .asLongAs(session => counter.getAndIncrement().equals("${total}/$limit"))
17:34:10.486 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - one error found
17:34:10.487 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation failed (CompilerInterface)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `.asLongAs(session => session.get("${counter}").equals("10"))` looks like `while (counter == 10)`. Maybe loop while the counter is *not* equal to 10?

Comment: while loop doesn't work. Throws same error. Also tried with .doIf(session => session("counter") != 10) same error of counter.

Comment: I don't know the API, but you could try `.asLongAs(session => session.get("${counter}").notEquals("10"))`. Also, try to use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA to write code, it's much easier since possible code is suggested and errors can be seen while writing the code.

Comment: Nope that's also not working. i've tried ```.asLongAs(session => session("counter").as[Int] < 10)``` but unable to set session value of counter in asLongAs condition. Is ```session.set("counter", increaseCounter)``` looks okay??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at top you define a variable "counter" and here

```
.asLongAs(session => session.get("${counter}").equals("10"))
```

you use the variable from the session.
I could not see where you add the variable to the session before. This means this gives an exception when accessing or null.
One solution would be

```
.asLongAs(session => session.("$counter").asOption[String].equals("10"))
```

you may add a ! before to invert the result then the loop is executed until counter is 10.

P.S.: I'm quit sure it is not relevant for you anymore but the question is still showing up on google so it may help someone.